# How to merge these two pieces of Python list code?

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, list

1.

```
json_obj = response.json()
az = []
for item in json_obj['DATA']['data']:
    az.append(item['name'])
print (az)
```

Number 1 code result is this

```
['Australia', 'CHINA', 'Combodia', 'EUROPE', 'HONG KONG', 'INDIA',         
'INDONESIA', 'JAPAN', 'KOREA', 'MALAYSIA', 'Myanmar', 'New Zealand', 
'PHILIPPINES', 'Russia', 'senchilles', 'SINGAPORE', 'Sri Lanka', 'TAIWAN', 
'TestCountry', 'THAILAND', 'UNITED KINGDOM', 'USA', 'Vietnam', 'XY Test 
Country']
```

and then i add this code

2.

```
for i in az:
     print(az.index(i) +1, end=' ')
     print(" ",i)
```

and result code number 2 is like this

```
1   Australia
2   CHINA
3   Combodia
4   EUROPE
5   HONG KONG
6   INDIA
7   INDONESIA
8   JAPAN
9   KOREA
10   MALAYSIA
11   Myanmar
12   New Zealand
13   PHILIPPINES
14   Russia
15   senchilles
16   SINGAPORE
17   Sri Lanka
18   TAIWAN
19   TestCountry
20   THAILAND
21   UNITED KINGDOM
22   USA
23   Vietnam
24   XY Test Country
```

my question is how to insert the result of code number 2 into one variable so i can call the 'az' list like below

```
reply = az
response.status = falcon.HTTP_200
response.body = self.format_message(message,reply)
```

Comment: push generated data into list inside for loop

Comment: Should `az` be a list of strings, or one large string with embedded newlines, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
az = ['Australia', 'CHINA', 'Combodia', 'EUROPE', 'HONG KONG', 'INDIA',         
'INDONESIA', 'JAPAN', 'KOREA', 'MALAYSIA', 'Myanmar', 'New Zealand', 
'PHILIPPINES', 'Russia', 'senchilles', 'SINGAPORE', 'Sri Lanka', 'TAIWAN', 
'TestCountry', 'THAILAND', 'UNITED KINGDOM', 'USA', 'Vietnam', 'XY Test 
Country']

s='\n'.join("{}\t{}".format(*x) for x in enumerate(az, start=1))

print(s)

1       Australia
2       CHINA
3       Combodia
4       EUROPE
5       HONG KONG
6       INDIA
7       INDONESIA
8       JAPAN
9       KOREA
10      MALAYSIA
11      Myanmar
12      New Zealand
13      PHILIPPINES
14      Russia
15      senchilles
16      SINGAPORE
17      Sri Lanka
18      TAIWAN
19      TestCountry
20      THAILAND
21      UNITED KINGDOM
22      USA
23      Vietnam
24      XY Test Country
```

Comment: Thanks Julien, exactly what i'm looking for :)

Comment: @Julien: I have tried to come up with a better question title. I've edited, but if you have a better idea, please edit again - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation would work for this.

```
x = ''
for i in az:
  x += str(az.index(i) + 1)+'\t'+i+'\n'
print(x)
```

x Holds the complete string of 24 countries.